# Link shortener target URL changed, Internet Explorer goes to old link

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, url

I'm using the tiny.cc URL shortener to shorten a link to a file (hosted on Dropbox.) I need to update the file every now and then, but this requires me to upload a new copy, changing the URL. I change the URL on tiny.cc and it works fine, with no problems on Chrome.

However, on IE it goes to the old page for some reason. Additionally in a program I'm developing I use URLDownloadToFile() to download it, and it downloads the old copy. Does anyone know why, and what I can do about it?

Comment: You probably need to clear IE's cache. Open IE and do Ctrl+F5 on any page.

Comment: Done it, still shows the old file.

Comment: However, if I go into private browsing and open the link, then view the link in normal browsing I get the new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, use Ctrl+Shift+P in IE and visit the page - it will delete the cached version. In code you can use DeleteUrlCacheEntry(url).

Comment: They keyboard shortcut in question does not delete the cache version of the page but pens a new In Private Browsing window.

Comment: That's right - viewing the page downloads a 'fresh copy' of the page, and to do that the page must be deleted from the cache (which is why it works in a normal window afterwards)